# when i am changing the fontsize of Text ,CircleAvatar margin is also changing ,why this happening?

Tags: flutter

when i am changing the fontsize of Text ,CircleAvatar margin is also changing ,why this happening?

code:

```
 home: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,

          children: [
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 50.0,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
            ),
            Text(
              'michael scofield',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'pacifico',
                fontSize: 40.0,
                color: Colors.white,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This was happened because you didn't use crossAxisAlignment. It was automatically set to the center as default. Use following code to set it aligned to the left.

```
Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 50.0,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage('images/pic.jpg'),
                ),
                Text(
                  'michael scofield',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'pacifico',
                    fontSize: 60.0,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Please add some context to explain the code sections (or check that you have not incorrectly formatted all of your question as code).
when i try post code.its shows this error?
it really frustrated me.please trell me wqhat to do